# Toggle Error Location panel in syntastic

Tags: vim, syntastic

How can I set a keyboard shortcut to toggle Syntastic Error Location List Panel in vim.

`:Errors` - Shows Location Panel

`:lclose` - Hides the Location Panel

I'm very new to VimScript, if there would be a way to **check visibility of the Location List Panel**. This should be fairly easy to do.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I do not know how to differentiate* quickfix and location lists, but in place of checking whether location list is displayed I would suggest just closing it and checking whether number of windows shown has changed:

```
function! ToggleErrors()
    let old_last_winnr = winnr('$')
    lclose
    if old_last_winnr == winnr('$')
        " Nothing was closed, open syntastic error location panel
        Errors
    endif
endfunction
```

* if you are fine with the solution that will try `lclose` if any is active check for the buffer displayed with buftype quickfix:

```
function! ToggleErrors()
    if empty(filter(tabpagebuflist(), 'getbufvar(v:val, "&buftype") is# "quickfix"'))
         " No location/quickfix list shown, open syntastic error location panel
         Errors
    else
        lclose
    endif
endfunction
```

. Note that `lclose` will not close quickfix list.

To toggle the Error Panel with Ctrl-e you can use the following mapping

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-e> :<C-u>call ToggleErrors()<CR>
```

Comment: How do you see the quickfix panel? Not sure if the docs mention about it.

Comment: @AkshayAurora `:vimgrep`, `:grep`, `:make` and so on all use quickfix list. `:copen` will show it. Docs do mention this, `:vimgrep` is the example in the second paragraph of `:h quickfix`. There are location list counterparts for all of these commands though: `:lvimgrep`, `:lgrep`, `:lmake` and so on.

Comment: Thanks. However, when using `gvim -p` to edit multiple files, each time I move out and back to the tab, the location list reappears. Neither its visibility status nor its height is persistent. Anyway, I ended up setting `g:syntastic_auto_loc_list` to `0` and now I activate it manually so I don't mind.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Syntastic help](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt), the command to close Syntastic error window is :

```
:SyntasticReset
```

Comment: neatest solution.